# Remove ability to close from taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I would like to remove the ability for a user to close a window in my application from the taskbar in windows 7:

[image]

The close button in the image should not be available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Usability nightmare!

Comment: Don't do this. Or at least give the users an (easy to find) option to opt out of this behaviour.

Comment: Isn't this classed as malicious programming?

Comment: Why do you want torture your user?

Comment: I created an app long time ago that needed to be ALWAYS turned on, disabling any possibility for user to close it, unless he/she knew a password.  The computer was provided to do only one task, and there were no need to close the app, unless you were about to do something nasty.  So please, why are you questioning OPs motives, and don't try to give him something to work with?

Comment: Just to clarify, the user can close the form, I just needed them to do it on the form its self, with a button provided. But I changed the code to work on the closing event. In hindsight I should have done that from the start. Thanks

Comment: Actually I don't get why it would be a "Usability Nightmare", .NET offers you the option to remove the close, maximize and minimize buttons from a form (Controlbox = false), what is the difference between that, and removing what I want to remove. Because now you are forcing the user to use your buttons on form for closing etc, but they can just close it from the jump list. That does not make sense! What is the point of removing the controlbox, if users can just close from the jump list?

Comment: Something like this would be useful in a kiosk environment. Don't vote the question down just because you don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do this.  Window managing/decorating is left to the window manager, you should rather handle the "close" event in some way, and avoid the applicaiton exiting.

Also, middle clicking (mouse2) on any part of that preview will also close the window, so it's not a matter of just hiding **that** button.

Comment: +1, and also thanks for that middle click info – I actually never tried that :o